# Why is UE looking on the D:\ drive? It's causing crashes

Tags: windows, crash, unreal-engine5

As the title says, I'm getting assertion errors for files located on the D:\ drive, but my install is plain vanilla C:\ drive.

Assertion failed: ... [File:D:\build...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using the nonfull source Unreal Engine.

For nonfull source Unreal, I know with Unreal's config for Visual Studio Code they use a source file map to map to your system's Unreal Engine path for debugging purposes. I'm sure they also do this with other IDE/Editors whenever possible.

Currently there's a bug with the Window's Unreal config for VSCode. In launch.json, where the soureFileMap setting is, they forgot to escape the '\' causing a malformed json file.

I do fix this in my VSCode extension for people who do use VSCode.
https://gist.github.com/boocs/f63a4878156295b6e854cac68672f305

Unfortunately I haven't tested if it works, just escaping the '\', because I'd need to find code that causes that exception.